# 100% height table layout, with scrollable columns

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a simple table layout, with the following basic requirements:

- It must stretch to 100% height
- It if content exceeds 100% of the viewport, then a scroll bar should be displayed.

This [example code in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/beardtwizzle/RyTLz/1/) works fine in webkit, however in Firefox, etc. it appears that its not translating correctly.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percentage based dimensions (width and height) don't work with `overflow:auto` in Mozilla or IE.

The layout engine must already know what the height of the element is before it can apply an `overflow:auto` to the element.

Hence `.scrollable { background: red; height:700px; overflow: auto; }` will work fine in Mozilla and IE (700px being some arbitrary value).